# How to access values in datetime Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I have something similar to this

```
s= "2010-02-12 12:12:10"
r= repr(datetime.datetime(*time.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")[:6]))
print r
```

The value gets printed out is `datetime.datetime(2010, 2, 12, 12, 12, 10)`

My question is: how do I access each value in r? For example, I only want the value for the year, which is 2012. I tried doing r[0] but it gives me letter 'd' instead...

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `repr` turns it into a string (or actually, a *repr*esentation of the `datetime` object that Python can work with. str() is for turning thing into strings).

Keep it simpler:

```
>>> r = datetime.datetime(*time.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")[:6])
>>> r.year
2010
```

Answer (score 7):

Why do you use `repr()`?

```
>>> s = "2010-02-12 12:12:10"
>>> r = datetime.datetime(*time.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")[:6])
>>> r.year
2010
```

More information about `date` objects here: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#date-objects

Answer (score 4):

You can access year attribute directly

```
datetime.date.today().year
```